# How to kill webpack service if I start it using npm? (ps aux | grep webpack varies every time)

Tags: macos, shell, webpack, service, process

In `lib/assets` directory, I ran `npm install`, and my `package.json` file in that directory have the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": blah
    "bundle": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "lint": blah
  },
```

so I can start webpack by calling `npm run bundle` or `npm run bundle -- -p`

How do I kill it?

**Note**: `ps aux | grep webpack` gives different pid every time:

```
USER               PID  COMMAND

my-name         85294  grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn webapck

my-name         85305  grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn webapck

my-name         85316  grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn webapck
```

Comment: ctrl + c does not kill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstand how webpack works.

I thought Webpack will keep running in background and compile the asset for me.

To explain why I think that way, let me start from the beginning:

I fork a rails project from GitHub (https://github.com/DMPRoadmap/roadmap), get it up and running, but I realise that it doesn't display images when I access the rails application website through browser, and its layout are not applied (stylesheets). I realise I need to use webpack to compile these asset.

So I started webpack by running `npm install` and `npm run bundle`, and the terminal show me something like this:

```
$ npm run bundle

> roadmap@1.0.0 bundle /Users/my-name/dev/testing/dmp-roadmap/lib/assets
> webpack


Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 1af8780dadb3d5abe275
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 7360ms
                                                 Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                           images/bournemouth_logo.png    16.1 kB          [emitted]
                fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot    20.1 kB          [emitted]
               fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff    23.4 kB          [emitted]
                fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf    45.4 kB          [emitted]
                fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg     109 kB          [emitted]
                         fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot     166 kB          [emitted]
                       fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2    77.2 kB          [emitted]
                        fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff      98 kB          [emitted]
                         fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf     166 kB          [emitted]
                         fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg     444 kB          [emitted]  [big]
  ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/content.inline.min.css    3.17 kB          [emitted]
         ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/content.min.css    3.57 kB          [emitted]
 ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce-small.eot    9.49 kB          [emitted]
 ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce-small.svg    24.7 kB          [emitted]
 ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce-small.ttf     9.3 kB          [emitted]
./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce-small.woff    9.38 kB          [emitted]
       ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.eot    17.6 kB          [emitted]
       ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.svg      46 kB          [emitted]
       ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.ttf    17.4 kB          [emitted]
      ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff    17.5 kB          [emitted]
          ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/img/anchor.gif   53 bytes          [emitted]
          ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/img/loader.gif    2.61 kB          [emitted]
          ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/img/object.gif  152 bytes          [emitted]
           ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/img/trans.gif   43 bytes          [emitted]
            ./stylesheets/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css      40 kB          [emitted]
                            javascripts/application.js    3.26 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  application
                                 javascripts/vendor.js     317 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                           stylesheets/application.css     201 kB       0  [emitted]         application
                       images/2013_Jisc_Logo_RGB72.png    2.12 kB          [emitted]
                                        images/asc.gif   54 bytes          [emitted]
                                 images/background.jpg    1.69 kB          [emitted]
                                         images/bg.gif   64 bytes          [emitted]
                             images/dcc_logo_white.png    3.03 kB          [emitted]
                                   images/dcc_logo.png  907 bytes          [emitted]
              fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2      18 kB          [emitted]
                                       images/desc.gif   54 bytes          [emitted]
                                   images/download.png    2.55 kB          [emitted]
                                 images/fullscreen.png  341 bytes          [emitted]
                                    images/favicon.ico    1.15 kB          [emitted]
                 images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png    8.78 kB          [emitted]
                                images/help_button.png  557 bytes          [emitted]
                       images/glyphicons-halflings.png    12.8 kB          [emitted]
                                       images/logo.png    15.5 kB          [emitted]
                              images/minus_laranja.png  408 bytes          [emitted]
                             images/lancaster_logo.png    26.2 kB          [emitted]
                           images/lse-library_logo.png    18.2 kB          [emitted]
                               images/plus_laranja.png  781 bytes          [emitted]
                              images/question-mark.png    2.57 kB          [emitted]
                                      images/rails.png    6.65 kB          [emitted]
                             images/newcastle_logo.png     142 kB          [emitted]
                                     images/remove.png  681 bytes          [emitted]
                   images/roadmap_logo_orange_grey.png    3.81 kB          [emitted]
                  images/roadmap_logo_orange_white.png    3.56 kB          [emitted]
                               images/salford_logo.png    8.36 kB          [emitted]
                            images/select2-spinner.gif    1.85 kB          [emitted]
                                    images/select2.png  613 bytes          [emitted]
                                  images/select2x2.png  845 bytes          [emitted]
                             images/uc3_logo_white.png    3.11 kB          [emitted]
                                 images/screencast.jpg     103 kB          [emitted]
                                   images/uc3_logo.jpg       4 kB          [emitted]
                                    images/ue_logo.png    26.9 kB          [emitted]
          videos/index.files/html5video/fullscreen.png  341 bytes          [emitted]
            videos/index.files/html5video/flashfox.swf     4.9 kB          [emitted]
             videos/index.files/html5video/html5ext.js    3.51 kB          [emitted]
          videos/index.files/html5video/screencast.jpg     103 kB          [emitted]
          videos/index.files/html5video/screencast.mp4    12.3 MB          [emitted]  [big]
         videos/index.files/html5video/screencast.webm    13.7 MB          [emitted]  [big]
          videos/index.files/html5video/screencast.m4v    13.8 MB          [emitted]  [big]
          videos/index.files/html5video/screencast.ogv    24.7 MB          [emitted]  [big]
  [15] ./javascripts/utils/links.js 4.71 kB {0} [built]
  [18] ./javascripts/utils/paginable.js 1.09 kB {0} [built]
  [27] ./javascripts/views/org_admin/questions/sharedEventHandlers.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
  [28] ./javascripts/views/org_admin/question_options/index.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
 [156] multi jquery timeago.js jquery-accessible-autocomplete-list-aria/jquery-accessible-autocomplete-list-aria jquery-ujs 64 bytes {1} [built]
 [159] multi ./javascripts/application.js ./stylesheets/application.scss 40 bytes {0} [built]
 [160] ./javascripts/application.js 1.77 kB {0} [built]
 [236] ./javascripts/views/shared/sign_in_form.js 1.81 kB {0} [built]
 [238] ./javascripts/views/super_admin/themes/new_edit.js 424 bytes {0} [built]
 [239] ./javascripts/views/super_admin/users/edit.js 485 bytes {0} [built]
 [240] ./javascripts/views/usage/index.js 7.67 kB {0} [built]
 [289] ./javascripts/views/users/notification_preferences.js 622 bytes {0} [built]
 [290] ./javascripts/views/users/admin_grant_permissions.js 4.43 kB {0} [built]
 [291] ./javascripts/views/super_admin/notifications/edit.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
 [292] ./stylesheets/application.scss 41 bytes {0} [built]
    + 291 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!stylesheets/application.scss:
     10 assets
       [1] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./stylesheets/application.scss 214 kB {0} [built]
        + 13 hidden modules
```

Since running `npm run bundle` doesn't display the terminal new line prompt (I'm talking about the `$` character), I thought it is like a server, constantly serving the asset files for my rails application to use.

I refresh the website and it shows the image and layout beautifully.

I stop the webpack by pressing CTRL + C and reload the website again, it still shows the image and layout beautifully and I falsely concluded that the webpack is now serving the file in background.

But I'm wrong.

After I stopped the webpack process by pressing CTRL + C, Webpack stopped serving the files. But since it already compiled the asset files and store them in the public directory inside my project directory before, my website just use the files in there. This is the actual reason why the website still shows the images and layout beautifully.

So, to stop `npm run bundle` which is the same as calling `webpack` in my case, I can indeed simply just press CTRL + C.

For `npm run bundle -- -p`, I don't know what it is doing now, after running it (given that I have already run npm run bundle and stop it using  CTRL + C), the website stops showing the images and layout properly.

Also, the reason that I see the PID keep changing when I call `ps aux | grep webpack` is because `grep` is the process that I'm seeing and each time I start a `grep`, it will be a new different process, so it will have different PID. The webpack process is already stopped when I press CTRL + C.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work in bash:

```
$ ps -ef | grep webpack | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```